# SQLite / MySQL compatibility issue

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I know SQL in SQLite is not completely implemented the same way as in MySql. My problem with the following queries is, that they are not compatible and I like to avoid a conditional `if <DBMS> ... else`

*SQLite query*

```
UPDATE sorties SET state = '#' 
WHERE `key` IN (
  SELECT `key` FROM sorties 
  INNER JOIN reports AS r 
    ON r.sortieId=sorties.`key`);
```

Error on MySQL:

> SQL Error (1093): Table 'sorties' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

*MySQL query* (adapted from [here](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/))

```
UPDATE sorties AS s SET s.state='#'
WHERE s.`key` IN ( 
  SELECT t.sortieId FROM (
    SELECT r.sortieId AS sortieId
    FROM reports AS r
      INNER JOIN sorties AS sort
        ON sort.`key`=r.sortieId) 
    AS t);
```

Error on SQLite:

> SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: UPDATE sorties AS s SET s.state='#'
>   WHERE s.`key` IN ( SELECT t.sortieId FROM (
>   SELECT DISTINCT r.sortieId AS sortieId
>   FROM reports AS r
>   INNER JOIN sorties AS sort
>       ON sort.`key`=r.sortieId) AS t); [ near "AS": syntax error ]
>   Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
>   Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]

I can't figure out how to make this queries work on both systems equally!

All I want to have is, that each `state` of `sorties` must be '#' when it's `key` can be found in `reports.sortieId`.

Maybe there is a different approach for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first command reads the `key` value from the `sorties` table in the subquery, and then checks whether those key values exist in the `sorties` table in the outer statement. That check is superfluous; you can just compare the values to the ones in `reports` directly:

```
UPDATE sorties
SET state = '#'
WHERE key IN (SELECT sortieId
              FROM reports);
```

As for the second command, SQLite does not support aliasing a table used in INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE because those commands work only on a single table. You can just remove the `AS s` and replace `s` with `sorties` everywhere.

Comment: Great thanks, sometimes it is much easier than it appears.